# Windows Server 2008 r2: Updating RDP 6.1 to 7.1

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-services

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 RDP Session Hosts. They are using the RDP 6.1 protocol. How can I update to 7.1? Do I have to install a software or can it be configured?

Comment: Are you asking about the client to connect to your RDSH servers?

Comment: No, about the server

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about that unless you're connecting from the server out.  You can download the updated client though if you need to update it.  7.0 is included with R2.

Comment: What I mean is that my Remote Desktop server has only protocol 6.1 installed. You see this if you go to "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration"

Comment: Ya, I see where you're looking, mine shows 7.1.  7.0 is the default with R2 so there will be a setting to change that. I'm looking at my configs now.

Comment: My OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard without SP. Maybe it comes with the SP? I try it now ...

Answer (score 3):

RDP 7.1 was introduced in Windows 7 SP1 & Server 2008 R2 SP1 & it adds RemoteFX functionality. So to use RDP 7.1 you need both client side & server side support.
In your case if you have already updated your clients, you need to install SP1 on your Windows Server 2008 R2 ([link to download SP1 for Windows Server 2008 R2 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)).
There is also RDP 8.0 out there - which is included in Server 2012 & Windows 8. Clients for this version available for legacy operating systems, i.e. Windows 7 & Server 2008 :)